# Bootstrap 3 hidden-xs not working in safari os x

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari

The code below works for every browser except for OS X Safari (most recent version) in which the contact info content is hidden no matter what the screen size. The contact info is supposed to hide when the screen size is 767 px and smaller. Why is safari hiding the content when it shouldn't and how do I fix it?

I'm using the sparkling theme by colorlib with a child theme. The theme uses bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="logo col-sm-4">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="btn navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                        <div id="logo">
                            logo here
                        </div><!-- end of #logo -->


                                                </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="site-navigation-inner col-sm-8">
                    <div class=" hidden-xs contact-info">
                        <p>contact info here</p>
                        <hr class="hr" />
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"> menu here</div>                      

                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Tested on Safari 11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7) which is the most current version as of 9/21/2017.  `hidden-xs` hides the contact information as expected when the viewport is sized appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. Funny how the update fixed the problem. So to update my question, the problem lies in the previous versions of safari (10.1.2). How do I get it to function properly in the previous versions? The site is rppsplash.com.